# Fast and precise nearest step floating point ceiling/flooring without Decimal.quantize

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, ieee-754, numba

The following function is supposed to ceil the given number to the nearest step:

```
def ceil_step(x, step):
    return math.ceil(x / step) * step
```

This works well... until it does not:

```
print(ceil_step(1000.365, 0.01)) # 1000.37
print(ceil_step(1000.369, 0.01)) # 1000.37
print(ceil_step(1000.370, 0.01)) # 1000.37
print(ceil_step(1000.371, 0.01)) # 1000.38

print(ceil_step(10000.365, 0.01)) # 10000.37
print(ceil_step(10000.369, 0.01)) # 10000.37
print(ceil_step(10000.370, 0.01)) # 10000.380000000001
print(ceil_step(10000.371, 0.01)) # 10000.380000000001
```

A working implementation would be:

```
def ceil_step(x, step):
    return Decimal(str(x)).quantize(Decimal(str(step)), rounding=ROUND_CEILING)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use it because I am writing Numba-accelerated Python code. Therefore, my question: Is there a way to implement the `ceil_step` (and analogously `floor_step`) function such that it only uses basic floating point operations or Numba-supported function calls and produces reliable results?

Comment: Your `ceil_step` is actually sort working for `10000.370` and broken for `1000.370`. Commonly, Python implementations use IEEE-754 binary64 for floating-point. When `10000.370` is converted to the nearest value representable in this format, the result is 10000.370000000000800355337560176849365234375. Thus, the ceiling of that with respect to multiples of .01 is 10000.38. That number is not representable in binary64, so your result is an approximation. When `1000.370` is converted to binary64 the result is 1000.3700000000000045474735088646411895751953125, so the ceiling ought to be 1000.37…

Comment: … However, your `ceil_step` got a rounding error when it divided by .01, and the result was 100037 instead of a number a little larger. So it got the result you expected, but the wrong result, by accident. Your code has four rounding errors for each `ceil_step` call: One converting the decimal source text of the first operand to binary64, one converting `0.01` to binary64, one dividing, and one multiplying. Furthermore, the only multiples of .01 that are exactly representable in binary64 are .00, .25, .50, and .75, so it is not possible to return correct ceilings for any other cases…

Comment: … There will always be some error. Floating-point arithmetic is designed to approximate real-number arithmetic, and they work well with continuous functions (with reasonable slopes). When you attempt to evaluate discontinuous functions, problems like this arise. If you are expecting accurate results near discontinuities (such as each jump in the ceiling function), then you must take extraordinary care to design your code correctly, using a thorough knowledge of floating-point arithmetic. It may be that the problem you are trying to use `ceil_step` for is not suited for floating-point.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for the insights. I guess you are right and I should not really be using floating points. However, I don't have much of a choice - so I have to work around the issues. I will most likely just deduct some small number before applying the ceil logic.

Comment: @EricPostpischil would appreciate if you could comment on my own answer below.

Answer (score 1):

For now, I have settled with the following function:

```py
def round_step(x, step, method=-1):
    eps = np.finfo(np.float64).eps
    digits = math.ceil(-np.log10(step))
    return round(math.ceil(x * (1 - eps) / step) * step, digits)
```

The multiplication with `(1 - eps)` makes sure (hopefully!) that `math.ceil` does not overshoot. The `round` is necessary to get rid of stuff like `...0000000001`.

Comment: In attempting to cure overshoot, this will undershoot for some numbers. As my comment above, floating-point arithmetic does not handle discontinuous functions well. This function cannot be a general solution. Whether it solves a problem for your specific application is unknown to anybody who does not know the needs and circumstances of your application. Generally, people trying this sort of thing are on the wrong track.

Comment: I agree that this is not a general solution. However, my numbers (and the step argument) are not small (i.e. much bigger than eps, in the range of what you have seen in the examples). In this context, I think it should work just fine.